# i want to add value on specific point in array php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to determine what is the type of filed in my array from below code.

```
foreach($question->questionsOptions as $option){ 
     $servey_detail_arr['option'][$option->question_id][] = array('value'=>$option->label,'id'=>$option->option_id,'option'=>$option->label);
}
```

The above code create below array. Now i want to insert type of filed in my array. i have written in below array in comment where i want the value.

```
 Array
    (
        [option] => Array
            (
                [96] => Array
                    (
                        //i want add here a value means type radio 
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => karachi
                                [id] => 49
                                [option] => karachi
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => islamabad
                                [id] => 50
                                [option] => islamabad
                            )

                    )

                [97] => Array
                    (


**i want add here a value means type datepicker** 
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => date
                                [id] => 53
                                [option] => date
                            )

                    )


                [100] => Array
                    (
                         //i want add here a value means type checbox 
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => checkbox1
                                [id] => 55
                                [option] => checkbox1
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => checkbox2
                                [id] => 56
                                [option] => checkbox2
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Any other solution will be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: you can actually, but I think you must have a condition in your foreach to check whether to insert the additional item or not.

Comment: Yeah i have but how I add i am not undertsand

Comment: My Suggestion is make hidden field in your form based on question id for eg : <input type="hidden" name="type_<?php echo $question->id ?>" value="<?php echo "your field type" ?>" />. In your php you can get based on question id and insert where ever you want.

Comment: Your answer for some extent is healthy. this will be work for me but i am finding a proper solution which i mentioned in my comment. Thank you @Muthu17

Comment: So in your case, 96, 97, 100 are the questions are dynamic and it will come from database and generate the dynamic form right?

Comment: Yes. but I am creating a web service not a form. Thank you

Comment: If you need proper solution means, make one field your question table and give your question type as column and get your type from database itself

Comment: Yes exectly @Muthu17

Comment: the work which you done can achived very simply but you made very complex . you not got my point what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below condition inside foreach loop

```
           if (array_key_exists('96', $servey_detail_arr['option'][$option->question_id])) {
    $servey_detail_arr['option'][$option->question_id][] = array('type'=>'radio');
}
if (array_key_exists('97', $servey_detail_arr['option'][$option->question_id])) {
    $servey_detail_arr['option'][$option->question_id][] = array('type'=>'datepicker');
}
if (array_key_exists('98', $servey_detail_arr['option'][$option->question_id])) {
    $servey_detail_arr['option'][$option->question_id][] = array('type'=>'checkbox');
}
```

Comment: thanks. this will be add multiple type radio in 96  but i want only one time

Comment: you can use array_push so it will not create multiple items.